# Probability of subsequence 123456 in $n$ rolls, combinatorics approach?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

I was trying to solve this problem:

> We roll a 6-sided die n times. What is the probability that all faces have appeared in order, in some
> six consecutive rolls (i.e., what is the probability that the subsequence 123456 appears among the n
> rolls)?

My immediate reflex was to use Markov chains, but I soon backed down because of how tedious the calculations seemed. I know that it's supposed to be the correct way to tackle it but I've tried something different that ended up being wrong and I'd really appreciate it if you could help pointing out my mistakes.

So I decided to count the number of sequences containing the subsequence 123456. Indeed, any sequence of $n$ numbers is equiprobable of probability $\frac{1}{6^n}$. When we consider such we can pick any of $n-5$ starting point for the subsequence 123456, the rest of the sequence doesn't matter and each term can be any number of $\left\{1,2,3,4,5,6\right\}$ so we've got $6^{n-6}$ ways to pick the remaining numbers. So following this reasoning, I would be tempted to say that the wanted probability is $\frac{(n-5)6^{n-6}}{6^n} = \frac{n-5}{6^6}$ which obviously doesn't make sense because I could take an $n$ that's strictly greater than $6^6$ and it would be a probability strictly greater than $1$...

I really struggle with combinatorics like that and I never know why my reasoning is wrong.

Comment: The events of getting 123456 starting at the first roll and getting 123456 starting at the second roll are mutually exclusive. Also, you are overcounting the situations where the subsequence 123456 occurs more than once.

Comment: Sorry for being slow but isn't it precisely the mutual exclusivity that allows me to add $6^{n-6}$ ways of picking the remaining numbers $n-5$ times, because the starting point of the considered subsequence is either the roll $1,2,\dots,n-5$? Also, the problem doesn't specify that the subsequence 123456 appears only once.

Comment: Consider 123456123456, you've counted it twice when you should only count it once

Comment: Oh ok got it because by considering every possible sequence of $n-6$ numbers I already implicitly account for every other starting point for the subsequence 123456, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Let $p(n)$ be the probability of having 123456 in $n$ rolls. Then, we have the  following recurrence by conditioning on the first time that the sequence appears.

For $\color{blue}{6\le n \le 11}$:

$$p(n)=\color{blue}{(n-5) \left ( \frac{1}{6} \right ) ^6}$$

For $\color{blue}{n \ge 12}$:

$$p(n)=(11-5) \left ( \frac{1}{6} \right )^6+\sum_{i=7}^{n-5}(1-p(i-1)) \left ( \frac{1}{6} \right ) ^6= \color{blue}{\left ( \frac{1}{6} \right ) ^6 \left [n-5-\sum_{i=6}^{n-6}p(i) \right ]}$$

The above can be used to **efficiently** compute the probability $p(n)$.

From the above, for $n \ge 12$,  one can obtain another recurrence (obtained in another answer based on a different reasoning):

$$p(n)=p(n-1)+\left ( \frac{1}{6} \right ) ^6 \left [1-p(n-6) \right ]$$

as follows:

$$p(n)-p(n-1)=\left ( \frac{1}{6} \right ) ^6 \left [n-5-\sum_{i=6}^{n-6}p(i)- \left( (n-1)-5-\sum_{i=6}^{n-1-6}p(i) \right ) \right ]=\left ( \frac{1}{6} \right ) ^6 \left [1-p(n-6) \right ].$$

**More interestingly**, using the recurrence, **the probability can be determined in each range $6k\le n < 6(k+1)$ for $k\in \mathbb N$.** For $k=1$, $6\le n < 12$, we have $$p(n)=(n-5) \left ( \frac{1}{6} \right ) ^6.$$

Let us set $k=2$ and find the formula of $p(n)$ for $\color{blue}{12\le n < 18}$:

$$p(n)=\left ( \frac{1}{6} \right ) ^6 \left [n-5-\sum_{i=6}^{n-6}p(i) \right ]=\left ( \frac{1}{6} \right ) ^6 \left [n-5-\left ( \frac{1}{6} \right ) ^6\sum_{i=6}^{n-6}(i-5) \right ]=\color{blue}{\left ( \frac{1}{6} \right ) ^6 \left [n-5-\left ( \frac{1}{6} \right ) ^6\frac{(n-10)(n-11)}{2} \right ]}.$$

This can be similarly used to obtain the formula for $k=3$ (and the next values of $k$) as we have the formulas for $p(6), \dots, p(11)$ and $p(12), \dots, p(17)$.

This procedure reveals that for $6k\le n < 6(k+1)$ the probability $p(n)$ is **a polynomial of max order $k$**:

$$p(n)=a_0+a_1n+\dots+ a_k n^k.$$

---

We could also use inclusion-exclusion, but the result is complex (see the closed-form formula obtained in another answer).

I **doubt** that a simple formula can be presented for $p(n)$ for $6k\le n < 6(k+1)$ for any $k \in \mathbb N$.

**Update 1:**

I realized that for $\color{orange}{n \ge 12 }$, the following is a very good approximation of $p(n)$:

$$p(n)=\color{orange}{\left ( \frac{1}{6} \right ) ^6 \left [n-5-\left ( \frac{1}{6} \right ) ^6\frac{(n-10)(n-11)}{2} \right ]}.$$

For $\color{orange}{n \le 100}$, the maximum error is less than $\color{orange}{9.72195267432557\text{E-}10}$

For $\color{orange}{n \le 1000}$, the maximum error is less than $\color{orange}{1.55551907611573E\text{E-}6}$.

For $\color{orange}{n \le 10000}$, the maximum error is less than $\color{orange}{0.00154961233453441}$.

For example, for $n=100$, $p(100)$ is $\color{blue}{0.00203434079881172}$, while the approximate value from the above formula is $\color{orange}{0.00203433982661645}$.

As another example, for $n=10000$, $p(10000)$ is $\color{blue}{0.192855678224992}$, while the approximate value from the above formula is $\color{orange}{0.191306065890458}$.

**Update 2:**

Finally, using a numerical study, I could obtain $\color{red}{\text{the exact general formula}}$ of  $p(n)$ for $6k\le n < 6(k+1)$ for any $k \in \mathbb N$:

$$p(n)=\left ( \frac{1}{6} \right ) ^6 (n-5) -\left ( \frac{1}{6} \right ) ^{2 \times 6}\frac{(n-10)(n-11)}{2!}+\left ( \frac{1}{6} \right ) ^{3 \times 6}\frac{(n-15)(n-16)(n-17)}{3!} \dots (-1)^{k-1}\left ( \frac{1}{6} \right ) ^{k \times 6}\frac{(n-(6k-k))\dots (n-(6k-1))}{k!}.$$

$$\fbox{$p(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{k}  (-1)^{i-1}\left( \frac{1}{6} \right ) ^{6i}\,\frac{\prod_{j=1}^{i}(n-(6i-j))}{i!}, \quad 6k\le n < 6(k+1).$}$$

In fact, this could be aldo obtained from the formula given in another answer using inclusion-exclusion after some simplifications.

Answer (score 0):

Let us denote by $f(n)$ the number of sequences of $n$ die rolls where the subsequence $123456$ occurs. We can deduce the following recurrent relation for $f(n)$: $$f(n)=6f(n-1)+(6^{n-6}-f(n-6)).$$ Indeed, if the subsequence $123456$ occurs in the first $n-1$ then we should count this sequence in, and it can be prolonged with any of the $6$ die rolls. Otherwise the last $6$ rolls must be $123456$ and there is no $123456$ in the first $n-6$ rolls.

This formula is already good enough. We have $f(0)=$ $f(1)=$ $f(2)= $ $f(3)=$ $f(4)=$ $f(5)=0$. Then one by one we can calculate $f(n)$ for any $n$. The answer to your question will be $f(n)/6^n$. This number grows quite slowly. For example, if $n=100$ then the answer is just barely above $2$ per mille: $\approx 0.002034340798812$.

Now there is actually a way to solve this recurrence. I’ve tried doing so, but free access Wolfram Alpha won’t let me compute this. I can however describe the maths. Consider the equation $$x^6-6x^5+1=0.$$ It has $6$ different (complex) roots, their approximate values are: $$x_1\approx 0.716838, x_2 \approx 5.99987,$$ $$ x_3\approx -0.55999-0.39661i, x_4\approx -0.55999+0.39661i, $$ $$x_5\approx 0.20164-0.67313i,x_6\approx 0.20164+0.67313i.$$

Now consider this system of $6$ linear equations with $6$ unknowns $c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4$, $c_5$, $c_6$: $$\sum_{i=1}^6 c_ix_i^j + 6^j = 0, \quad j = 0,1,2,3,4,5.$$

Unfortunately, this system of equations is quite large and Wolfram Alpha won’t accept the input. If we chop the numbers, the calculation accuracy falls drastically. If this system is solved though, you have the answer for $f(n)$ for any $n$: $$f(n)= \sum_{i=1}^6 c_ix_i^n + 6^n.$$

Edit: So I managed to solve the linear equations system. So here is a good approximation formula for the answer: $$ f(n)/6^n = 1+ (0.028194 \cdot 0.716838^n+ (-1.000108)\cdot 5.99987^n+ $$ $$+(-0.017734-0.010752i)\cdot(-0.55999-0.39661i)^n + $$ $$+(-0.017734+0.010752i)\cdot(-0.55999+0.39661i)^n + $$ $$ + (0.003691-0.02415i)\cdot(0.20164-0.67313i)^n + $$ $$+(0.003691+0.02415i)\cdot(0.20164+0.67313i)^n   )/6^n.$$

Comment: I think it does not say "exactly once". It just says appears, so it can appear more than once. "there is no $123456$  in the first $n−6$ rolls" does not seem to be correct.

Comment: @alex.peter You didn’t quite catch the reasoning. If there is subsequence $123456$ in the first $n-6$ rolls then this sequence is already counted in the first summand.

Comment: You need clarification on that one then alike: "if it happens that some of $6(n-1)$ starts with $123456$, it will have another $123456$ among first $n-1$. What remains are those that strictly start with $123456$ and have no other $123456$ elsewhere." It is clear to you, but I need some parsing as you can see. I doubt it will make your answer less appealing or comprehensible.

Comment: And one more: If you rewrite it all in the form of probability (divide everything by $6^n$) you would get rid of $6^{n-6}$ getting a recurrence that is more to the point.

Answer (score 0):

If you denote $p_n=\mathbb{P}(\text{your event $n$ rolls})$, you can construct your recursion this way ($X_i$ is $i-th$ dice roll):
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(\text{your event $n$ rolls})=\mathbb{P}(\text{your event $n$ rolls}|X_1=1)+...+\mathbb{P}(\text{your event $n$ rolls}|X_1=6)
\end{equation}
In case that $X_1\neq 1$ we have $\mathbb{P}(\text{your event $n-1$ rolls})=p_{n-1}$. Otherwise, we have $X_1=1$ and:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(\text{your event $n$ rolls})=\mathbb{P}(\text{your event $n$ rolls}|X_1=1)+5p_{n-1}
\end{equation}
We just need to find the probability with the condition $X_1=1$. This can be done similarly:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(\text{your event $n$ rolls}|X_1=1)=\mathbb{P}(\text{your event $n$ rolls}|X_1=1,X_2=2)+\mathbb{P}(\text{your event $n$ rolls}|X_1=1,X_2=1)+\mathbb{P}(\text{your event $n$ rolls}|X_1=1|X_2=3)+...\mathbb{P}(\text{your event $n$ rolls}|X_1=1,X_2=6)
\end{equation}
Which leaves us with $p_{n-2}$ for every case that $X_2 \neq 2$, since we have $n-2$ rolls left.
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(\text{your event $n$ rolls}|X_1=1)=\mathbb{P}(\text{your event $n$ rolls}|X_1=1,X_2=2)+5p_{n-2}
\end{equation}
By continuing the process you will model the probability with recursion. It is obvious that $p_1=p_2=p_3=p_4=p_5=0$ and $p_6=\frac{1}{6^6}$.

Answer (score 0):

The inclusion-exclusion approach isn't that bad, since multiple occurrences can't overlap.  If there are $k$ occurrences of the subsequence $123456$, then there are $n-6k$ positions remaining; insert the $k$ occurrences as $k$ distinguished positions, giving $n-5k$ positions in total, of which $k$ are distinguished and may occur anywhere in the sequence.  So the number of sequences with $k$ specific occurrences and no constraint on the remaining positions is ${{n-5k}\choose{k}}6^{n-6k}$, for a probability contribution of
$$
\frac{{n-5k}\choose{k}}{(6k)^6}=\frac{(n-5k)!}{(n-6k)!k!6^{6k}}.
$$
The overall exact answer, then, is
$$
p(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor{n/6}\rfloor}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}(n-5k)!}{(n-6k)!k!6^{6k}}.
$$
Note that the number of terms needed to get an accurate result is initially very small, but grows with $n$... in general the terms start shrinking once $k \gg n / 6^6$.  I've compared this to the two other answers and found it agrees.  In particular, the exact answer for $n=100$ is
$$
\frac{341839694035418792417464432131969563500276811405811130807601584865147825}{168034625385820706300589060483039562895355892611356705643794230033306877952}.
$$