# What is the probability of rolling at least $n$ consecutive numbers when rolling $k$ dice?

Tags: probability, dice

I am trying to code a game that turned out to be more complicated than expected. The complication comes down to a function that attempts to calculate the chance of at least $n$ consecutive numbers out of a total of $k$ dice rolled. The function only has to work for integer values of $n$ and $k$, and $2\le n\le k\le 6$. I am looking for a formula I can use to calculate all possibilities and store them as variables, or a javaScript function that can take parameters $n$ and $k$ and then do the calculation that way. I have been trying for a while now and cannot find a way to correctly calculate these probabilities to match experimental results. I have tried a lot of different javaScript function ideas to iterate and calculate these odds, but none of my attempts works for both $n=k=2$ and $n=3, k=6$. Example combinations that work for $n=3$ and $k=6$ are $1, 2, 3, 6, 6, 6; \; 3, 5, 2, 1, 4, 6$ and 1, 2, 3, 4, 6. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do the consecutive numbers need to appear consecutively, or do they just need to appear anywhere?  I'm not clear on whether the word "consecutive" refers to the numbers on the dice, or their positions, or both.  Can you [edit] the post to state this clearly?

Comment: Related problem of determining probability of appearing subsequence 123456 in 
$$ rolls: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4854023/1231520

Answer (score 2):

There are only $6^6 \approx 50,000$ possible sequences of 6 rolls.  Just enumerate all of them, and count how many meet your requirements.  A program to do that should finish in milliseconds.

Or, precompute the answer for each $k,n$ satisfying $2 \le n \le k \le 6$.  There are only 15 pairs of values $(n,k)$, so you can precompute the answer for each pair, and hardcode all of those in your code as a lookup table, and  just look up the desired entry at runtime.

Comment: The second part would have been my answer. The first part seems to assume that the consecutive numbers need to appear on consecutive rolls. The example $3,5,2,1,4,6$ that the OP later added to the question seems to indicate that that isn’t the intended interpretation.

Comment: @joriki, Oh gosh, I bet you are right.  I've edited my answer accordingly.  Shoot.  Thank you for pointing that out.